# Handling views with Repository pattern

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

What is the best way to handle views (classes that does not represent entities but are used, for instance, to bind a DropDown-list) using a repository pattern? For instance I have a following Customer Entity

```
public class Customer {
  Guid ID {get;set;}
  string FirstName {get;set;}
  string LastName {get;set;}
  List<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}
```

and a repository

```
public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer> {
   Customer GetByID(Guid id) { ... }
   List<Customer> GetAll() { ... }
   // Insert/Delete/Update Customer etc.
}
```

Now I want to fill a DropDown with a list of customers along with their base address, using their ID's as a value property. I have a stored procedure returning this data and I can retrieve its result into a list of following objects :

```
public class CustomerWithBaseAddress {
  public Guid CustomerID {get;set;}
  public string FullNameWithBaseAddress { get;set; }
}
```

Should Customer repository return such objects or should it be managed by a different, specialized repository (but without Save/Delete operations) ?

Answer (score 2):

A repository should only handle an aggregate root and it's aggregates. This means that it could handle `Customer`, `CustomerOrders` etc.

A `CustomerWithBaseAddress` however is a ViewModel and has nothing to do with the database. It should be built in your controller by using repositories.

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) or similar for the mapping.

Comment: What do you mean "It should be built in your controller by using repositories"? - If I understand corretly, then in such case, if I used repository to retrieve customers and then map these results to CustomerWithBaseAddress wouldn't that be a huge waste of resources? (Customer aggregate is in fact much more complex than I wrote in my example and therefore I would retrieve a lot of Customer data that I don't need in my CustomerWithBaseAddress view model).

Comment: I misread. I though that  `CustomerWithBaseAddress` inherited `Customer`. Apologies. Since `CustomerWithBaseAddress` is created by a database query of some sort I would put it in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you need objects like this that are not part of your domain and it is too expensive to assemble them from domain objects, create a lookup service.  Basically just a service that calls a special repository in a separate assembly that is not part of your formal domain model.  As long as you are only using the objects obtained from this service as lookups etc they are throwaways and do not require managing.

You have to be careful about using this approach with objects that can be misued as domain object however.  Make sure you do not use the CustmerWithBaseAddress for anything other than selection from a dropdown etc.  So as soon as you have selected the CustmerWithBaseAddress object you should get the real Customer object  and not let the CustmerWithBaseAdress leak out into the rest of the application code.

Comment: Also have a look at the CQRS architecture model.